# Schema Conversion from String datatype to Array(Map(Array)) datatype in Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, schema, apache-spark-sql

We are reading  data  from dynamo db so we are getting datatype as string, but we want writing string data type as array(map(array))

string Data :

> {"policy_details":[{"cdhid":" 123","p2cid":" NA", "roleDesc":" NA","positionnum":"NA"}, {"cdhid":" 1234","p2cid":" NA", "roleDesc":" NA","positionnum":"NA"}]}

output required:
string data type need to convert to `ARRAY(MAP(ARRAY))`

We have tried with below schema:

```py
ArrayType([
    StructField("policy_num", MapType(ArrayType([
        StructField("cdhid", StringType(), True), 
        StructField("role_id", StringType(), True),
        StructField("role_desc", StringType(), True)
    ])))
])
```

getting below issue:

> elementType [StructField(cdhid,StringType,true),
>   StructField(role_id,StringType,true),
>   StructField(role_desc,StringType,true)] should be an instance of < class 'pyspark.sql.types.DataType' >

Comment: which version of spark do you use ? what have you tried ? You current "schema" does not fit your data. explain what is the expected output with your current data. You current data structure is `map(array(map))`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your data, the schema your want is not the one that fits. 
The schema of you data is :

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as T

schm = T.StructType([T.StructField("policy_details",T.ArrayType(T.StructType([ 
        T.StructField("cdhid", T.StringType(), True), 
        T.StructField("p2cid", T.StringType(), True), 
        T.StructField("roleDesc", T.StringType(), True),  
        T.StructField("positionnum", T.StringType(), True), 
    ])), True)])
```

Then, you just need to use the [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) function.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.show()                                                                                                         
+--------------------+                                                          
|             db_data|
+--------------------+
|{"policy_details"...|
+--------------------+

new_df = df.select(F.from_json("db_data", schm).alias("data"))

new_df.printSchema()                                                                                              
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- policy_details: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- cdhid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- p2cid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- roleDesc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- positionnum: string (nullable = true)
```

---

**EDIT** : If you want to use `MapType`, you can replace the schema with :

```py
schm = T.StructType([
    T.StructField(
        "policy_details",
        T.ArrayType(T.MapType(
            T.StringType(), 
            T.StringType()
        )), 
        True
    )
])
```